# Phpmailer - Unique email attachments

Tags: php, sql, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send multiple emails with unique attachment. Currently, I am successful in sending multiple emails to different addresses from the databases.

**PROBLEM:** Whenever I send emails, each email sent has multiple attachments.

**WHAT SHOULD BE:** An email should have 1 unique attachment only. Like, abc@gmail.com should have abc.pdf attached, bnm@gmail.com should have bnm.pdf attached, and etc.

So far, I have the code below. Maybe it's in my loop that cause the problem, or something. Please comment if you have an idea. Thanks.

```
$email = "select si.email_address, sr.control_no  
            from sa_student si
            left join sa_result sr on sr.control_no = si.control_no
            where schoolyear = '2013'
           ";

if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{ 

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
  {

   $mail->AddAddress($row['email_address']);

   $mail->AddAttachment("fpdf/pdf_reports/docu/".$row['control_no'].".pdf");

   }

$mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

$mail->ClearAttachments();

}
```

Comment: your add attachment code inside the loop and sending the email out side loop so move $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

$mail->ClearAttachments(); inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `clear` and `send` methods into your while loop:

```
$email = "select si.email_address, sr.control_no  
        from sa_student si
        left join sa_sase_result sr on sr.control_no = si.control_no
        where schoolyear = '2013'
       ";

if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{ 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
   {
       $mail->AddAddress($row['email_address']);
       $mail->AddAttachment("fpdf/pdf_reports/docu/".$row['control_no'].".pdf");
       $mail->Send();
       $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
       $mail->ClearAttachments();
   }
}
```